# Incorrect weighty in gridbaglayout

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I want to make a GUI in Java, using GridBagLayout. This is what I want in the end :

[image]

Therefore, I followed some instructions I found on the Internet, and here is the code I wrote :

```
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    gc.weightx = 7;
    gc.weighty = 7;
    panel.add(new JLabel("title"), gc, 0, 0, 2, 1);
    panel.add(new JButton("button 1"), gc, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    panel.add(new JButton("button 2"), gc, 3, 0, 1, 1);
    panel.add(new JButton("button 3"), gc, 4, 0, 1, 1);
    panel.add(new JButton("button 4"), gc, 5, 0, 1, 1);
    panel.add(new JButton("button 5"), gc, 6, 0, 1, 1);
    panel.add(new JLabel("subtitle"), gc, 0, 1, 7, 1);   
    panel.add(new JButton("list"), gc, 0, 2, 2, 4);  
    panel.add(new JButton("button"), gc, 0, 6, 1, 1);    
    panel.add(new JButton("button"), gc, 1, 6, 1, 1);
    panel.add(new JButton("table"), gc, 2, 2, 5, 5);
```

My function add :

```
public void add(Component component, GridBagConstraints constraints, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    constraints.gridx = x;
    constraints.gridy = y;
    constraints.gridwidth = width;
    constraints.gridheight = height;
    this.add(component, constraints);
}
```

But, I have this in the end :

[image]

As you can see, the table does not take 5 cells in height at all, and the list does not take 4 cells. Does anybody know why it acts like this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you add:

```
    constraints.weightx = (double) width / 7.0;
    constraints.weighty = (double) height / 7.0;
```

to your add method.

Comment: Or some other way to determine the weight of the component in relation to the grid size

Comment: Aw yeah ! Thank you very much ^^ Could you explain why please ?

Comment: Unfortunately not really ... Weights should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and indicate how much space the component takes up vertically and horizontally... so far, so good... I am however not exactly sure why this is not also declared by the gridwidth and height

Comment: But basically, if you calculate your weights to add up to 1.0 for height and width you should be safe

Comment: Ah, I read that the extra space was given to the component which have the greater weightx and weighty... So I just gave a weighty = 1 to the table and the list, and the rest is 0. Thanks again for your help :)